# Why can't mathematics be formalised in terms of classes rather than sets?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, soft-question, foundations

I've always been curious about the seeming compulsion to found mathematics upon sets, be it ZF(C) or some other system. Of course, there are other approaches these days like category theory and type theory (themselves inextricably linked by the Curry–Howard–Lambek correspondence), but these rather seek an entirely different approach. What I'm really getting at is: why can't we simply deal with (improper) classes? That is, throw away sets as reified mathematical objects and just deal with the classes implicitly defined by predicates in some logical system. Does this indeed make certain areas of mathematics inaccessible? Are there other problems I might not have considered? I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me here in a general way, albeit perhaps also with some specific cases within mathematical subfields.

Comment: The question seems to admit many interpretations, but the most natural one seems to be that you want to deal only with classes and that these (being "improper") will not be elements of other classes. So the elements of classes will have to be some non-class entities that haven't been specified. If, on the other hand, you want to allow some (but not all?) classes to be members of others, then just define "set" to mean "class that can be a member of another class" and you're back to set-class theories like NBG. Maybe you intend something entirely different, but what?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Well, I left this aspect open somewhat on purpose. But let's be more specific, for the sake of argument. First, we could envisage a universe of discourse being something like the naturals (recursively defined), with only first-order classes. Alternatively, we could work in some higher-order logic, thus allowing classes to be members of other classes, in a stratified manner.

Comment: Who say's we can't deal with classes? Of course we can. Arnold Oberschelp does this for example. And his classes are so flexible that there is little difference anymore between handling classes and handling sets. Of course we can also deal with classes by relabeling them as sets in a bigger universe. This is what many people in category theory do when they encounter size-problems.

Comment: You misunderstand though, @JohannesHahn. My point is: can we eliminate the seemingly arbitrary ontology of sets altogether?

Comment: Such variations have been studied by Vopěnka and Hájek, *The Theory of Semisets*. That book is not easy to read though!

Comment: Does anyone who made a close vote here want to actually *justify* it? Clearly some people have understood the question just fine...

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: Sounds nasty, yes!

Comment: I voted to close because there was no clear question here. Rhetorical questions in philosophical areas, with no clear content, may indeed be part of life, but they are not (nor should they be) part of MathOverflow.

Comment: Noldorin, you have an interesting question which could deserve a discussion from like-minded individuals.  This forum is the wrong place for it.  The closest place on the SE network for such a discussion is the chat rooms.  This forum is more for question and answer format: read the FAQ for what formats and content are encouraged here.  If you have a specific question that avails itself of a specific answer and is in line with the intent of this forum, you are encouraged to ask that kind of question.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: Thank you for the advice. That sounds fair enough, so I'll try to target the chat room in the future!

Comment: I'm going to remove comments that started us in the direction of incivility. Noldorin has asked why the votes to close, which is perfectly reasonable. So are responses from closers like Andreas Blass, who sets a nice tone for civility. Let's keep it that way, please.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Sounds fair. I don't want it getting out of hand either. Best nip this in the bud while it's still pretty minor!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting together your two remarks

> just deal with the classes implicitly defined by predicates in some logical system.

and

> we could envisage a universe of discourse being something like the naturals (recursively defined), with only first-order classes.

seems to me to yield an informal description of [full second-order arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic), $Z_2$.

As to whether mathematics can be formalized in such a system, the answer is yes, virtually all mainstream mathematics can even be formalized in weak subsystems of $Z_2$. See the book [Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/) by Stephen Simpson.

Comment: Intriguing! Thank you for this answer. This is very much what I was hoping for. Do these formalisations avoid set theory altogether then, I take it?

Comment: I am reading you as wanting to "eliminate the ontology of sets" by letting *every* predicate function as a definable collection. $Z_2$ does this via the full comprehension scheme.

Comment: Yep, this is very much what I'm interested in. Thanks Nik.

Comment: I should add that full comprehension allows predicates which reference quantification over all predicates. If that kind of circularity bothers you, look at the subsystem $ACA$ (which still suffices for, arguably, all or nearly all mainstream mathematics).

Comment: Fascinating. So ACA is an impredicative second-order system over the universe of naturals, and it suffices for virtually all mathematics? Why on Earth is it not more mainstream then, I wonder?

Comment: @Noldorin: Because working with set theory is much easier than working with arithmetic; because ZFC allows you to "forget your foundation" when working in "virtually all mathematics"; because model theory is much easier to work with when you have access to actual semantics, even if you want to talk about uncountable models (e.g. $\Bbb R$) without reducing to their countable counterparts; because sets are not that hard to understand, and once you forget about them they're gone, but encoding things into integers is harder; and more.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, I think in practice it actually makes little difference, since certain classes would take the place of sets. For me, model theory just happens to be the traditional way of dealing with the semantics of formal mathematics; there are plenty of other equally good ones (and better from certain points of view). I mean to say, model theory is essentially just an algebraic way of understanding logic and foundational mathematics. Algebraists and most mathematicians love it for that reason, I feel.

Comment: @Noldorin: If you have only access to subsets of $\Bbb N$, then no matter how hard you try, you will never have access to objects of size $>\frak c$. And even in the case of uncountable objects, I'm not sure whether or not you will have easy access as you would with set theory. "Doable" does not mean "Easily doable", in fact it usually means "Doable, after much work which requires deep understanding from the get go, that most people won't bother to fully gain". I also disagree with your latter assessment. You only consider the applied part of model theory, not the entire field.

Comment: @Noldorin: I mean, you can formalize $\sf ZFC$ in a theory like $\sf PA$ or $\sf PRA$, and then have all the rest of your formalization as syntactic derivations from that meta-theory; you can insist that this is the way you work with. Huzzah, all the mathematics has been formalized within finitary number theory; and you can formalize and work with $\sf GBC$ instead if you prefer. But is that an easy solution to work with?

Comment: Okay, then do please tell me how model theory is useful beyond this perspective? As far as I'm concerned, it has bootstrapping properties otherwise.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, you can surely operate on the level of classes in such a system, since it's second-order. After all, real numbers must ultimately be constructed as hereditary sets, within ZFC.

Comment: @Noldorin: (1) I am not familiar enough with the subsystems of second-order arithmetic and how easy/difficult it is to construct semantics for the real numbers with them. (2) What about accessing objects larger than $\frak c$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the notation $\frak c$. But if you mean "sets" of cardinality greater than $\aleph_1$, you be right in that that may require higher than 2nd-order.

Comment: @Noldorin: $\frak c$ is the cardinality of the continuum, which may or may not be equal to $\aleph_1$ -- depending on the continuum hypothesis. But let us stop now, I feel that we should apologize to Nik for flooding his inbox. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh I see, fair point. Yes, you are probably right there: $\frak c$ classes can be constructed in 2nd-order surely, but above that... my intuition says not. Yes, sorry for the flooding Nik!

Comment: Noldorin and @AsafKaragila: no need to apologize. I agree with most of what both of you said.

Answer (score 9):

You ask

> Why can't mathematics be formalised in terms of classes rather than sets?

The answer is that it can, and several standard accounts do precisely this. In particular, Gödel himself did this, for his version of what is now known as Gödel-Bernays set theory GBC (or von Neumann-Gödel-Bernays set theory NBGC) has only classes, not sets, as fundamental objects, and all the axioms refer only to classes. (One then introduces the concept of *set* as a defined term, a special kind of class, namely, a class that is a member of another class.) So this seems to be a central case that develops the theory as you like, and many contemporary accounts of GBC, such as Mendelson's, also use Gödel's version with only classes.

Meanwhile, it is also common, perhaps more common, to present the GBC theory as a two-sorted theory, as Bernays did, with both sets and classes. See page 14 of Kanamori's article [Bernays and set theory](http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/17.pdf) for informed comparison and discussion. The two presentations of the theory are easily interpreted in one another, and so the difference is widely viewed as a mathematically unimportant cosmetic difference.

Comment: Is this the same system referred to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory? If so, it seems to be discussing the two-sorted version. But apparently there's a logically equivalent one-sorted version that only deals with classes?

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia gives the common two-sorted version, but Goedel's version was one-sorted, using only classes.

Comment: Aha. Now, it's equivalent to ZF in expressive power?

Comment: No, it is more expressive, because it is able to express statements about classes that may not be definable. For example, the Kunen inconsistency is a more powerful assertion in GBC than it is in ZFC, if one takes it in ZFC to refer only to definable classes. Meanwhile, it is conservative over ZFC for assertions about sets---that is, it doesn't prove any new facts about sets.

Comment: I see. I would presume the axiomatic system of GBC resembles that of ZFC in many ways then? My own inclinations are finitary, so either a classically or strictly finitary system would be of more interest to me here, not that this isn't!

Comment: Yes, even though GBC refers to classes and not sets, it is really an account of set theory. It is finitely axiomatizable, however, but the subject of the theory is of course infinitary.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I've up-voted both your and Nik Weaver's answer, because they have both proven enlightening and relevant, though I'll wait a bit longer before deciding which to accept.

Comment: Shouldn't you be attending a lecture?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Are you speaking to me? If so, I think I've attended all the lectures available here at the conference in Bonn http://www.hcm.uni-bonn.de/events/eventpages/2014/infinity-computability-and-metamathematics/. Have I missed one?

Comment: @Joel: For some reason I was sure that Kanovei's lecture was this afternoon and the timing seemed right about when you posted the answer. But now I see that I was wrong on both accounts. So never mind. Shame I couldn't make it, it's not often that you come across the big pond!

Comment: Oh, his lecture is tomorrow, and I had some good conversations with him at the meeting.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not there to hear that lecture. It seem really interesting to me, for obvious reasons.

Comment: In any case, perhaps next time you've crossed the pond we'll be able to meet up for a drink. And who knows, maybe I'll end up crossing to the other side before then!